# Does UIPickerView support the new iOS 5 appearance API?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am customizing the design of a UIPickerView. I want to know whether it supports the new iOS 5 appearance API or not.

It is because I could not find such information about using the new appearance API in UIPickerView. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot find such information because `UIPickerView` does not support the any appearance customizations (beyond those inherited by its superclasses).

Put differently, no effort was made to make `UIPickerView` respond to manipulations via its appearance proxy.